# How to create an address of solana by using python?

Tags: wallet, python

I want to generate the address of solana by using python how could I do that?like in web3.py we create an ethereum account/address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Solana.py module , which provides the function to create a solana address using the keypair fucntion.  Here is the reference https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/core/keypair/ link

Comment: I'm using this code and generates a pair and get the public key too but unable to decode the pvt key of the pair

I'm not getting the pvt key of pair

Comment: code is that

import solana
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.keypair import Keypair

def create_account():
    acount = Keypair.generate()
    
    print("Public Key:",acount.public_key)
    print("Private Key:",acount.secret_key)
    


create_account()

Comment: To decode it use https://pypi.org/project/base58/ library .

Comment: I'm getting this in pvt key 

Private Key: b'\xd4r2\xacS<\x99:\xa3\xee\xc2\x94\x91\x95\xa8r\xd5r0\xaf\xa5\xb5#\xa6 N\xf0U\xbb\xa3\x8a!\xe0\x19\xcb\xdd\xd0ug\xf0CS\xbc[\xf1\xd0\x8c\xa2;\xc0\xc4\xf9o\xa8\x8a\x8f\x02\x7f\x15\x8d\x87\x14\xed\xd3'

and I tried the base58 decoder but it was unable to decode it

Comment: keypair = Keypair.generate() which will generate the keypair , now do this bytes(keypair.public_key).hex() that should return the public key . Same goes for secret key as well.

Comment: Does this still work? I have been trying it but keep getting ‘No module name solana.keypair’